# How to read the pickled igraph graph object from old version by new version igraph

Tags: python, igraph

I have programmed up a system with previous version of igraph (forgot which version it is), everything is fine and now installed new version of igraph. The program doesn't run through any more.

The error is:

```
'module' object has no attribute 'Graph'
```

It seems to be that igraph module do not have Graph class anymore?

```
import igraph as ig
ig.Graph()

'module' object has no attribute 'Graph'
```

I have now the pickled igraph graph object from old version, how can I read it out in new version?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `igraph` still has a `Graph` class. Could it be the case that there is some other module in your Python path that is also called `igraph` and that shadows the "real" igraph module? What does `dir(ig)` and `ig.__file__` show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also have this error message, by me It was caused by install:
The first time I've installed igraph

```
    pip install igraph
```

It was "successfully" installed, but get this message.

[The second time I installed so](http://igraph.org/python/):

```
    pip install python-igraph
```

After a much more verbose install-output: It works well, and there is Graph attribute.